# Azure PowerShell Set Tags Failure

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Using 1.0.1, running the below script does not generate errors. However, after viewing the VM Tags in the Preview Portal GUI, the tags do not show. What did I miss?

```
$tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"   -Name "myserver").Tags
$tags += @{Name1="name1";Value1="value1"}
$tags += @{Name2="name2";Value2="value2"}
$tags += @{Name3="name3";Value3="value3"}
$tags += @{Name4="name4";Value4="value4"}
Set-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "myserver" -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
```

Confirm:

```
Are you sure you want to update the following resource:
/subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myserver
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
```

Output:

```
Name              : b5bd3server044
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myserver
ResourceName      : myserver
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
ResourceGroupName : myresourcegroup
Location          : eastus2
SubscriptionId    : {guid}
Tags              : {}
Properties        : @{VmId={guid}; HardwareProfile=; StorageProfile=; OsProfile=; NetworkProfile=;
                    DiagnosticsProfile=; ProvisioningState=Succeeded}
```

Comment: Does the answer provided able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and found out the root cause of the issue.

It is because your new tags object properties are wrong, i.e. Name1, Value1...

You should use **Name** and **Value** as the tag properties only.

```
$tags += @{Name="name1";Value="value1"}
$tags += @{Name="name2";Value="value2"}
$tags += @{Name="name3";Value="value3"}
$tags += @{Name="name4";Value="value4"}
```

With just this fix you code should work perfectly fine.

Here is a good resource from Microsoft on using tags with Azure resources.

[Using tags to organize your Azure resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/#tagging-with-powershell)

Hope it helps.